# Wireshark with WANT_PACKET_EDITOR defined

Tags: wireshark

I want to modify some packets (HTTP) bits to specific value, that means I need to modify the packets manually. I see wireshark has an option named `WANT_PACKET_EDITOR` in `config.nmake` (I work on windows), uncomment it and compile, I see there is a new menu entry names "Edit Packet" under "Edit" menu, when I open a pcap file, move to a HTTP get packet, execute "Edit"->"Edit Packet", popup a window, this window looks exactly same as I double click on the packet in main window. The most important thing is, I can't do any modify in this popup window, so how does this functionality called "Edit Packet" but can't edit anyway?

Am I missing other things?

Comment: AFAIK this feature hasn't been used much. I suggest asking this question at wireshark-users@wireshark.org (https://www.wireshark.org/lists/

Answer (score 0):

I'm tested the packet editing functionality too with the newest wireshark code
compiled with `WANT_PACKET_EDITOR` activated .

And it seems to work, although this functionality is marked as experimental.

I have marked one selected packet and the called "Edit/Edit packet" from menu.
Packet editing dialog appears.

And then I have changed MAC source address of given packet from `FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:` to
`01:11:11:11:11:11:`, so that I positioned the cursor in the bottom hex view window
and I overwrite these FF values with new values.

Then I closes editing dialog and exported all packets into an another 
capture file with another name with File/Export specified packets (all packets).

Changed packet was right saved with the new value of destination address edited by me.

It seem to work.